# How does desktop client software aware container fail-over to another Docker Swarm worker node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We are running Docker Swarm with 10 workers nodes, and I created a Nginx port 80 container running on host network, which has replica = 1, this means within these 10 worker nodes, there will have 1 Nginx container running in these worker nodes.

Question: How does client PC know where to go if this Nginx container is floating around the worker nodes without fix IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a `service` over your ngix container. You can configure this service with [routing mesh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/). The routing mesh enables each node in the swarm to accept connections on published ports for any service running in the swarm so when you query any of the nodes in your cluster, you will be redirected to the container wherever it is.

```
$ docker service create \
  --name my-web \
  --publish published=80,target=80 \
  --replicas 1 \
  nginx
```

Comment: routing mesh only prevent container failed to run on a worker node, doesn't help if Docker node itself failed, correct?

Comment: you can query any node, so if node your are querying is down, you will not have any response at all. To prevent this situation you can use an external load balancer as stated in here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#configure-an-external-load-balancer